# Error in importing an image into r markdown

Tags: r, markdown, r-markdown

I want to import a local image into r markdown in order to covert my doc. to pdf

```
 > ![NS](image/NS.png)
 Error: unexpected '[' in "!["
```

the folder "image" is located in my directory

Comment: Is `>` supposed to be an interactive prompt? A Markdown blockquote character? How much of your code block is input, and how much is output?

Answer (score 12):

It looks like you are using that syntax in a code block. You can use code blocks to generate images, but embedding images should be done in the normal markdown part of the document. For example, your markdown document could look like:

````
Some text

```{r}
#This is a code block
mean(1:10)
```

![NS](image/NS.png)

Some more text.
````

Comment: Thanks, just putting it outside of the chunck did the trick, so easy but it was getting me cracy!! :)

Answer (score 3):

Just put this chunk in the document and render using knitr.

````
```{r ,echo=FALSE}
library(png)
library(grid)
img <- readPNG("image.png")
 grid.raster(img)
```
````

Comment: Is there a package for jpg files?

Comment: I don't know any r package for this task. However you can use shell (bash) packages such as imagemagick. 
Installation: `sudo apt-get install imagemagick`
convert images: `convert image.jpg image.png`